# Converting a SQL SELECT query into a DELETE query

Tags: sql

How would I turn this select query into a delete query? (deleting records from tbl_a_D_B_t_Items)

```
SELECT *
FROM
 tbl_a_D_B_t_Items
 LEFT JOIN
  tbl_tr_D_Items
  ON
   tbl_a_D_B_t_Items.D_t_ItemID=tbl_tr_D_Items.D_t_ItemID
WHERE
 (
    tbl_tr_D_Items.D_t_ItemID
    Is Null
 )
;
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE X FROM tbl_a_D_B_t_Items X
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_tr_D_Items Y
  ON
   X.D_t_ItemID=Y.D_t_ItemID
WHERE
 (
    Y.D_t_ItemID
    Is Null
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_a_D_B_t_Items a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_tr_D_Items d
                  WHERE a.D_t_ItemID = d.D_t_ItemID  
                 );
```

Comment: Ageed . NOT EXISTS would be much better and faster than with join.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this better:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_a_D_B_t_Items
WHERE D_t_ItemID NOT IN
  ( SELECT D_t_ItemID FROM tbl_tr_D_Items)
```